# Applying limits to the Trash on Debian Wheezy

Tags: gnome, debian, nautilus, trash

I'm using Debian Wheezy, with Gnome 3 and Nautilus and I was wondering if there was any way to limit the Trash to a certain total size or at least file age.

I'm in need of this as I usually handle many GB file sizes and trashing them makes them still use the whole space. Directly removing them could be an option but I would lose the ability to recover them (something I usually need for one or two days).

I also guess I could write a cron job to remove files from the Trash based on whatever criteria I want using the `find` command but I was hoping for a more 2014 solution.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `KDE`, you can adjust trash's size with `dolphin` file manager:

- Dolphin > Settings > Configure Dolphin > File management > Trash
- Set `limit to maximum size`
- Apply

Comment: Thanks but sorry, I'm using Gnome and Nautilus. I've updated the question to reflect this